# Setting symbology visibility to dynamic scale which changes based on specific maps in atlas composer

Tags: symbology, scale, atlas

I have a project where I wish to have four pages of maps for each region, with set symbology for each map level. However each region has a different scale that im working at.

for example region A the first map may be 1:1000, 1:10000, 1:50000, and 1:100000 while region B is 1:2000, 1:20000, 1:50000, 1:100000.

First two pages are variable based on the size of the project, while the last two are static because its a maximum for all the projects.

So i need my layers to show labels for region A at 1:1000 to 1:10000, and show labels in region B from 1:2000 to 1:2000 but not outside those scales.

Comment: Assuming that this is for QGIS, please always mention that software in your question body.  If you tag it as [tag:qgis] too, then your question is likely to be seen by many more QGIS users.